Definite article with names of public buildings consisting of two words
I'll cite some excerpts from the textbook "English Grammar in Use."
"Names of important public buildings and institutions are often two words. The first word is the name of a place (e.g., Manchester) or a person (e.g., Harvard). These names are usually without the." The author lists these names. He later continues with the following: "Most other buildings have names that include the."
I will list only the names of interest. These are the Sheraton Hotel, the Guggenheim Museum, and the Eiffel Tower. Each of these examples is a pair where the first word is a name, but the article the is used. This makes it feel like these examples contradict the rule mentioned earlier. Why did he use the phrase 'other buildings' if these other buildings correspond to the rule that he stated? Why didn't he state explicitly that these are exceptions, but rather used the word 'other' as if these words have nothing to do with the rule?
There is a possibility that the Sheraton Hotel isn't an important public building, so it has nothing to do with the rule, but the Guggenheim Museum and the Eiffel Tower are definitely important public buildings.
So here is a question: Do I understand the rule correctly?

It's not a rule, just a description of a tendency. Note that he says usually and most other buildings, not that a building named after a person never has the definite article.

Such advice is like saying "The ice on the lake is usually thick enough to walk on this time of year." You have to use an internet search engine and find out how the place name appears in articles written by news organizations and in books and on the institution's website.   There's no substitute for actual knowledge.

It really varies all over the place. Baltimore has the Meyerhoff Symphony Hall, while New York has (the the-free) Carnegie Hall. Reminds me of Granada’s Alhambra, typically referred to in English as the Alhambra, though the Al- is Arabic’s definite article. As though a Frenchman were to say, *"Je lis la The New York Times."

Sometimes the names of some public buildings include "The", others don't:  "The Ritz" and "Harrods" are a hotel and a shop in London.  The first name includes "The". "The Monument" includes it, but "Nelson's column" doesn't
Other buildings have two-word names, sometimes these include "The", and you've given some examples.  Sometimes they don't: "Buckingham Palace" sometimes it varies with the context and speaker:  "(The) Marble Arch".
One could go on, perhaps a trend would emerge. I note that names with an "apostrophe s" genitive such as "Nelson's Column" are very unlikely to have "The". But there is essentially no rule to be learned here.
See "the Eiffel Tower" or "Eiffel Tower"

I'm afraid I have to disagree about the Marble Arch. The name of the building or structure is customarily preceded by the definite article. It was intended in the 1820s to be one of a pair (the other being the Wellington Arch) making a triumphal entry to the then planned Buckingham Palace. The Marble Arch is one of London’s familiar sights
(Fig. 1). It has given its name to a tube station and hence to a district. The Georgian Group The latter two don't have articles.

One thing that irritates me about modern Londoners is the habit of preceding some local road names (in my view) inappropriately with 'the' e.g. the Waterloo Road, the Gloucester Road.

I have to admit that until today I had assumed that the Marble Arch was made entirely out of marble, and not, as I now find, merely clad in that stone.

@MichaelHarvey I cycled through "Marble Arch" most days for over a decade en route to work without ever thinking that the name might be preceded by the definite article. That's probably because the name refers both to the area and a tube (metro/underground) station. Googling it brings up at least as many references minus the article as with it. "Marble Arch" was also a convenient meeting point. Would you concede that usage has rather worn the article away?

I would 'concede' that the definite article is looking sickly, but since I was taken there on a school trip in 1960 and heard it called 'the Marble Arch', and read various accounts of its design and erection since then, it is hard to shake it off. I'm thinking also now of [the] Cutty Sark, [the] Mansion House, [the] [Victoria] Embankment, [the] Barbican... all tube or DLR stations and areas named after buidlings or structures, whose definite articles seem a bit shaky.

Here's a list of names where "the" is not part of the name.

Manchester [place name, no the]
Sheraton Hotel [no the]
Guggenheim Museum [no the, see the museum online]
Eiffel Tower [no the]

VERSUS:

The Empire State Building The Empire State Building
The Statue of Liberty [official name with the]
The Tower of London [official name takes the: The Tower of London

No the as part of the formal name of the place or institution, as found on a list or sign.
Ok, now when writing about these places in a sentence a "the" is often required as not using anything is not grammatical in English: Guggenheim Museum is very famous.
Example:
The Guggenheim Museum in New York City is very famous.
The Eiffel Tower is one of the most famous landmarks in the world.
Articles are used in sentences and are not necessarily part of the name.

Macy's and Harrod's are famous department stores.

No the. Probably because they sound plural due to the s and words in the plural don't need "the".
Apples are good.
Cars can be dangerous

I didn't list the names that adhere to the rule. These are Victoria Station, Canterbury Cathedral, Edinburgh Castle, Buckingham Palace, Cambridge University, and Sydney Harbor. The author states that we don't usually use 'the' with them, so we aren't supposed to use the article 'the' with them, and it won't be ungrammatical.

@snailontheslope There is no rule. There is the fact that the official names of some buildings take the and others do not. Again: it is not a rule. There are tons of two-word place names all over the Anglosphere that don't take the. But, you are missing my main point about the difference between listing and writing about these buildings. **Grand Central Station, Central Park Zoo, etc. etc, ad infinitum almost.

Nope, I got it. I'm trying to tell you that we usually won't use the definite article when writing about these places, and it won't be ungrammatical. The same applies to the names of buildings that are named after people, as you've already mentioned. I understand that this isn't a rule that is set in stone. I guess he made it up based on his observations of the language, so the students can depend on something. I'm not sure if it's really helpful. For my part, I concluded not to depend on it and check everything myself.

And you are wrong: You say there is a rule, and there isn't. There is listing and there is writing about it. The Edinburgh Castle I knew as a child, is not the Edinburgh Castle today. = writing as specific. Versus: Edinburgh Castle is very big.

You don't want to understand me. I've said that this isn't a real rule. This rule is a made-up one. He developed this rule to help students not to be overwhelmed in the real world, which doesn't really obey any rules. Your example here isn't applicable to the topic at hand, as it can be used to prove that it's OK to use the definite article with any name. I wasn't asking about that specific nuance of the English language.

I did answer your question: Some buildings have the as part of the title, some don't. That's the answer. But I then went beyond that easy fact.

Anyway, I'm grateful to you for your willingness to help!

@snailontheslope - a spelling note: Sydney Harbour is an aquatic playground for Sydneysiders. (Australia.com) Despite their 'Labor Party', the Aussies mainly follow British spelling conventions.

@Michael Harvey Thanks for your correction! I overlooked the exact spelling.

@MichaelHarvey The Sydney Harbour of today is not the one of yesteryear.
